# Can't pass variable to .getRange()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that gets a range who's size is based on a constant. My the code I've been trying is below

```
//Save range based on number of components
  var numComponents = 3;
  var compRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(15,3,numComponents,3);
  var compValues = compRange.getValues();
  var components = "";

  //Convert the components into paragraph form
  for (var row = 0; row <= numComponents ;row++){
    
      components = components + compValues[row][1] + " " + compValues[row][2] + " "+ compValues[row][0]+ "\n";
  };
```

Whenever I run this code, I get an error saying

> Error: Cannot read property 1 of undefined

When I replace `numComponents` with 3, the code works perfectly, however that will not always be the case. How can I make it work properly?

Comment: The code isn't complete. Please add a [mcve] included the textual error message (including file name and line number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is this expression `row <= numComponents`

Replace

```
for (var row = 0; row <= numComponents ;row++){
```

by

```
for (var row = 0; row < numComponents ;row++){
```